# Jest - Testing modals in React gives error

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-test-renderer

I am using `react-test-renderer` with Jest to test react components. But if I test a react-mui modal dialog like this:

```
describe('Dashboard', function () {
  let dashboard;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    testRenderer = TestRenderer.create(<MemoryRouter><Route component={Dashboard} /></MemoryRouter>);
    dashboard = testRenderer.root.findByType(Dashboard);
    await waitForExpect(() => expect(dashboard.instance.state.hasLoaded).toBeTruthy());
  });


  it('opens dialog on clicking the new class', async () => {
    const button = testRenderer.root.findByType(Button);
    expect(dashboard.instance.state.showDialog).toBeFalsy();
    button.props.onClick();
    expect(dashboard.instance.state.showDialog).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

But, then I get an error:

> Error: Failed: "Error: Uncaught 'Warning: An invalid container has
>   been provided. This may indicate that another renderer is being used
>   in addition to the test renderer. (For example, ReactDOM.createPortal
>   inside of a ReactTestRenderer tree.) This is not supported.%s'

How should I test then react portals to make this test work?

Comment: seems like known issue https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11565 with only workaround to mock `ReactDOM.createPortal`

Answer (score 11):

Try putting this in your tests:

```
beforeAll(() => {
    ReactDOM.createPortal = jest.fn((element, node) => {
        return element
    })
});
```

Comment: How does this code work? What is the reason that we need to put it?

Comment: @MaryamSaeidi I think you should add `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom` and add the beforeAll code just below the imports.

Comment: I tried this, but got `Cannot set property 'scrollTop' of null`.

Comment: Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')]
        at reportException (/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:66:24)





 The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(Portal)> component:
    
        at Portal (/node_modules/@mui/base/node/Portal/Portal.js:33:5)





Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollTop')]
        at reportException (/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:66:24)

Answer (score 8):

Based on Oliver's answer, but for TypeScript users:

```
describe("Tests", () => {
  const oldCreatePortal = ReactDOM.createPortal;
  beforeAll(() => {
    ReactDOM.createPortal = (node: ReactNode): ReactPortal =>
      node as ReactPortal;
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    ReactDOM.createPortal = oldCreatePortal;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the existing solutions don't address the root cause.

I needed to add jest mocks for all the sub-components in the component I was testing.

For example, consider this JSX that I want to test:

```
import { CustomTextInput } from 'components/CustomTextInput';
import { CustomButton } from 'components/CustomButton';

return (
  <>
    <CustomTextInput />
    <CustomButton />
  </>
)
```

I need to add mocks for `CustomTextInput` and `CustomButton` in my test file like this:

```
jest.mock(
  'components/CustomTextInput',
  () => ({ default: 'mock-CustomTextInput' }),
);

jest.mock(
  'components/CustomButton',
  () => ({ default: 'mock-CustomButton' }),
);
```