# Can't test Material-ui Modal with react test renderer

Tags: unit-testing, material-ui, react-test-renderer

When trying to write a simple test with jest lib for Modal component like this

```
import { Modal } from '@material-ui/core';
import React from 'react';
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';

describe('Material Modal test', () => {
  it('It should render', () => {
    const testRenderer = TestRenderer.create(
      <Modal open={true}>
        <div>Test</div>
      </Modal>
    );

    console.log(testRenderer.toJSON());
  });
});
```

I get an error:

```
 console.error node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:120
      Warning: An invalid container has been provided. This may indicate that another renderer is being used in addition to the test renderer. (For example, ReactDOM.createPortal inside of a ReactTestRenderer tree.) This is not supported.
          in div (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
          in ForwardRef(Portal) (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
          in ForwardRef(Modal) (at spinnerWaitingWindow.spec.tsx:10)
    console.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
      Error: Uncaught [TypeError: parentInstance.children.indexOf is not a function]
```

Did anyone have a clue why this happens and how to setup test library?

Comment: Ancient thread, but I had similar issue and it seems like setting up a jest mock function helps - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56257998/jest-testing-modals-in-react-gives-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock partially `react-dom` to escape the `createPortal` function trying to attach to a non existing dom element. Here's an example:

```
jest.mock('react-dom', () => {
    const actualModule = jest.requireActual('react-dom');
    return {
        ...actualModule,
        createPortal: node => node,
    };
});
```

To be on the safe side it's always a good idea to perform mocks cleanup after the suite has finished e.g.:

```
describe('Material modal test`, () => {

 afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
 });

})
```