# Errors when using React Testing Library and renderHook to test hooks with multiple contexts

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-testing-library

### Solved

Issue is tracked on [github](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11565)

I *was* attempting to test custom hooks using the react testing library, and the hook I was trying to put under test requires multiple context providers to work correctly. (authentication and notification)

The documentation [here](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/usage/advanced-hooks) only outlines creating a wrapper with a single provider like so:

```
const wrapper = ({ children }) => <ContextProvider>{children}</ContextProvider>
```

However, my implementation needed something more complex, like so:

```
const wrapper = ({ children }) => (
    <ToastProvider>
        <NotificationProvider>
            <AuthProvider>{children}</AuthProvider>
        </NotificationProvider>
    </ToastProvider>
);
```

This was was failing at every attempt with the errors:

```
TypeError: parentInstance.children.indexOf is not a function
```

OR

```
Invariant Violation: Drop(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

Leading me to believe there was no clear way to provide the right context without abandoning renderHook all together and building a test component that could fire off the necessary behaviors manually.

After a lot more digging I found this error buried in the logs:

```
Warning: An invalid container has been provided. This may indicate that another renderer is being used in addition to the test renderer. (For example, ReactDOM.createPortal inside of a ReactTestRenderer tree.) This is not supported.
```

Surely enough, it turns out there is a conflict with `react-test-renderer` and `react-dom` which causes calls to ReactDOM.createPortal to fail when under test. I assume this is somewhere in the ToastProvider, but the workaround is pretty simple.

Solved by adding this to the top of my test:

```
ReactDOM.createPortal = node => node
```

Comment: If you're unit testing useAuth you only need to test that it returns the result of `useContext(authContext)` so if you'll mock useContext and createContext you can test that.

Comment: I ended up rewriting this to reflect the real issue I was having and to be informational only. It is fine to wrap renderHook with multiple contexts so long as the are no conflicting renderers, which can occur between react-dom and react-test-renderer.

Comment: I wanted to mark https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56257998/jest-testing-modals-in-react-gives-error as a duplicate of this one as this has a much more elaborate desciption. Maybe you could rephrase it as a question and provide and accept your own answer? After that other similar questions can be linked to this one.